# How to create self updating Node.js application with GitHub Actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-actions

I have Node.js service running on different computers and need to make this service self-updating, with opportunity to schedule different time for update for each computer. I tried to use GitHub Actions, it has `on.schedule` option for triggering, but the time that I can set here is constant.

Is it possible to change this time dynamically?

If you know some tools for self-updating Node.js application, please recommend them.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is these process is polling your github resources, for example a package.json file. When a version changes it pulls down the source, builds it and starts the new process, detaches from it and stops it old process(the one who pulled the new source).

Comment: Yes, something like that, with custom schedule for updates.

Comment: U can use Jenkins

Comment: Do you need deploy new versions of your nodejs app in your remote servers, when a git push is performed in a specific branch?